# Redirecting in Ruby on Rails Controller using a method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is currently breaking the test for the controller file. It is for some reason not redirecting properly:

```
def edit
  redirect_if_nil(@user)
end

def redirect_if_nil(user)
  if user.nil?
    redirect_to :register_invalid_token, notice: "Your token was invalid" and return
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide the error log and the controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors. First, `:register_invalid_token` is not a valid redirect option. You should pass an Hash of options to compose the route or the route path.

Second, the `return` will return the `redirect_if_nil`, not the controller. Thus it's useless.

Assuming `register_invalid_token_path` is the route:

```
def edit
  redirect_if_nil(@user)
end

def redirect_if_nil(user)
  unless user
    redirect_to register_invalid_token_path, notice: "Your token was invalid"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
redirect_to :register_invalid_token, notice: "Your token was invalid" and return
```

To:

```
redirect_to :register_invalid_token, notice: "Your token was invalid" 
return
```